# Redirecting the content of a directory, but not the directory itself as well as some of its subdirectories and files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, httpd.conf

As we simplified the URLs of our profiles from `example.com/category/profile/` to `example.com/profile`, et cetera (including the automatic removal of all trailing slashes -- see [Vanity URLs without trailing slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33228428/vanity-urls-without-trailing-slashes)), we now need to redirect all inbound links bound for the old URLs. We found a way to do this with the following code (which also excludes the files and directories we needed to keep).

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/category/index [NC] #Excludes /category/index.html from redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/category/images [NC] #Excludes /category/images/ from redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/category/menu [NC] #Excludes /category/menu/ from redirect
RewriteRule ^category/(.+[^/]) /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

But this only works if we keep all the original directories that contain our individual profiles; if we delete these directories, the redirect no longer works. We tried the below, but that didn't help.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/category/index [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/category/images [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/category/menu [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^category/(.+[^/]) /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

We were looking into an alternative (and much simpler) way to do this using RedirectMatch (code below), but we did not find a way to exclude the directories we need to keep and this also did not remove any trailing slashes from the original, inbound links.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/category/(.*)$ /$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RedirectMatch ^/category/((?!index|images|menu|foo|bar)[^/]+)/?$ /$1
```

Comment: Hey @Starkeen -- you're a genius -- this worked! We'll be implementing this throughout FASHION NET right away. Thanks you!!!!