# Redirecting the content of a directory, except for the directory itself and some of its subdirectories and files on Nginx

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, nginx

@Starkeen solved this for an Apache configuration at [Redirecting the content of a directory, but not the directory itself as well as some of its subdirectories and files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33715867/redirecting-the-content-of-a-directory-but-not-the-directory-itself-as-well-as), but we'll soon be moving to Nginx.

His very elegant solution for Apache:

`RedirectMatch ^/category/((?!index|images|menu)[^/]+)/?$ /$1`

Here, everything in the `/category/` directory -- except for `/category/index.php`, the content of `/category/images/` and the content of `/category/menu/` -- is redirected to the root folder.

We tried the translation from htaccess to Nginx offered at http://winginx.com/en/htaccess,

```
location ~ ^/category/((?!index|images|menu)[^/]+)/?$ {
rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1 redirect;
}
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, when we finally give up searching for a solution and end up asking for help, we often find one soon after. Here it is -- it works perfectly:

```
rewrite ^/category/((?!index|images|menu)[^/]+)/(.*)$ /$1 permanent;
```