# How to access directory's index.php without a trailing slash AND not get 301 redirect (NGinx)

Tags: php, nginx, redirect

I have been looking to rewrite my api URLs so they don't have a trailing slash. I use NGinx and not Apache. I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18625794/6828099) to the same question for an Apache server, but it is not going to work out of the box for NGinx.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking [this sample Apache config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18625794/6828099) and used [a config rewrite service](https://winginx.com/en/htaccess) to convert the config to Nginx format. It produces a mostly working, but slightly broken solution. It accesses the URLs like it is supposed to, but it breaks accessing resources and causes the /api/index.php to be dumped as a download when accessing a non-existent file or directory in /api/.

I played around with the config to produce the below config which uses the html 404 message provided to the whole server.

## NGinx

```
location /api {
  if (-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/(.*[^/])$ /$1/;
  }
}
```

My File structure is:

```
/api/index.php
/api/hotbits/index.php
/api/cryptography/index.php
```

With the new config option, this translates to these functional URLs:

```
/api
/api/
/api/hotbits
/api/hotbits/
/api/cryptography
/api/cryptography/
```