# Remove trailing slash after directory with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, trailing-slash

I want to remove `/` when I want to get access to the index file in a subdirectory folder. For example: `www.example.com/test/dashboard/` to `www.example.com/test/dashboard`.

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove "/" to "/dashboard"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) $1%1/ [L]
```

It will not remove the `/` from the subdirectory.

Can you please show me an example of how I can remove the `/` with `.htaccess` when I want to get access to my subdirectory?

Comment: What is the URL you are actually linking to?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> # Remove "/" to "/dashboard"
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
> RewriteRule (.*) $1%1/ [L]
> ```

This doesn't "remove" anything. In fact, it will *append* a trailing slash to the end of the URL-path *and* query string, which seems a bit random?

However, you can't simply remove the trailing slash that occurs after a physical directory in the URL-path, since mod_dir will try to append it with a 301 redirect in order to "fix" the URL.

You can prevent mod_dir from appending the trailing slash with the `DirectorySlash Off` directive. However, you then need to manually append the trailing slash to the directory with an internal rewrite in order to correctly serve the "index file" (ie. the `DirectoryIndex` document).

I'm assuming you are linking to the directory without a trailing slash in your internal links.

Try the following instead in the *root* `.htaccess` file:

```
# Disable directory listings (mod_autoindex)
Options -Indexes

# Prevent mod_dir appending trailing slash to directories
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite the URL to append a trailing slash to directories (internally)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*[^/])$ $1/ [L]
```

A request for `/dashboard` (no trailing slash) that maps to a physical directory will be internally rewritten to `/dashboard/`, which will allow the "index file" to be served (by mod_dir also).

For security reasons, you need to ensure that directory listings (mod_autoindex) are disabled, otherwise, directory listings could potentially be generated for directories even when they contain a directory index document. See the [security warning in the Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) under the `DirectorySlash` directive.

You need to ensure that your browser cache is cleared before testing since the 301 (permanent) redirect by mod_dir (to append the trailing slash) will have certainly been cached by the browser.

#### Remove the trailing slash (optional)

You could implement a canonical redirect to actually "remove" the trailing slash from the URL, should there be any requests from third parties (or search engines) that include the trailing slash. (It should already be removed on all your internal links, so this is not required to make your site "work", however, it could be required for SEO to avoid potential *duplicate content*.)

I'm assuming you don't want the trailing slash on *any* URL.

You should add the following "redirect" before the *rewrite* above, immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive.

```
# Remove the trailing slash, should it appear on any 3rd party requests
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is to ensure we do not redirect the already written request (that appends the trailing slash) by the later rewrite, during the second pass of the rewrite engine. Alternatively, you could use the `END` flag (Apache 2.4) on the later rewrite.

---

**UPDATE:**

#### `.htaccess` file not in the root directory

The above assumes the `.htaccess` file is located in the document root (and therefore applies to *all* directories and subdirectories thereof). If, however, the `.htaccess` file is in a subdirectory then you will need to modify the external redirect (that "removes" the trailing slash), since the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches the URL-path *relative* to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file, not the root directory.

So, if the `.htaccess` file is located in a subdirectory then use the following "redirect" instead:

```
# Remove the trailing slash, should it appear on any 3rd party requests
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteRule /$ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

This requires an additional *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) to capture the relevant part of the URL-path from the `REQUEST_URI` server variable (that contains the full root-relative URL-path), instead of the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, which will omit the parent directory(s). The `%1` backreference (as opposed to `$1`) references the captured subpattern from the preceding *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive), as opposed to the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Incidentally, this will also work if the `.htaccess` file is in the document root.

Note that this is unable to "remove" the trailing slash from the subdirectory (that contains the `.htaccess` file) itself. For that you would *need* to make use of the `.htaccess` file in the parent directory (ie. document root).

## Summary

The complete `.htaccess` would then become:

```
# Disable directory listings (mod_autoindex)
Options -Indexes

# Prevent mod_dir appending trailing slash to directories
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

# Remove the trailing slash, should it appear on any 3rd party requests
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteRule /$ /%1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite the URL to append a trailing slash to directories (internally)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*[^/])$ $1/ [L]
```

Note there is no `RewriteBase` directive here.

Comment: thank you for this, but when i try it out i am getting this `Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`. Do you know why??

Comment: @chrisoojer A 403 would imply there is no "index file" (ie. `DirectoryIndex` document) in that directory? What is the name of the file in the directory you are wanting to serve?

Comment: @chrisoojer What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file (what is your custom `ErrorDocument` set to)? Please update your question with your complete `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thanks!  How to include subdirectories? When I try the ending slash in a subdir it redirect to url domain root

Comment: @Extrangeplanet The above would already include subdirectories, providing the `.htaccess` file is located in the document root. Otherwise, you likely have a conflict with your existing directives. (But as noted above, you should already be linking to the URL _without_ a trailing slash in your internal links, so there should be no redirect under "normal" conditions.)

Comment: @Extrangeplanet If the `.htaccess` file is in a subdirectory then you would need to update the external redirect rule to make use of the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @MrWhite Thanks hermano! It works for root too :)